# Fair traffic classification using TC

Tags: networking, kernel-modules, network-interface, tc, qos

I want to apply a `qdisc` I developed on myself (quite similar to `netem`) to several IP-addresses using the filter classifier. No problem this far, I could do so using the prio qdisc or HTB qdisc. But I don't want to prioritize the traffic from the different IP-addresses differently, I want the bandwidth to be fairly distributed, therefore prio is not an option. Also, I don't want to restrict the bandwidth, therefore HTB is not an option either.

Is there a disc that could be used for my purposes? What am I missing?